# "Code" button in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using CKEditor (currently using ver. 3.4.1 - I can upgrade if it's necessary) and I'm missing a possibility to use the `<code>` tag, either from the Format dropdown or via a button on the toolbar.

I couldn't find a plugin that would make this possible. I have also no experience or knowledge of how to write my own plugin for that.

Do you know of a plugin that might help me enable the "code" button/format (wrapping selected text into `<code>` tags)? If there is none, I would appreciate if you directed me to online resources about CKEditor plugin development (some sort of tutorial explaining the bare basics).

In case it's useful, [my site](http://www.umbrarumregnum.net/blog/2010/12/chain-it)'s using Drupal 6.19, [CKEditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), CKEditor 3.4.1. As for plugin development tutorials, I have already found [this](http://voofie.com/content/2/ckeditor-plugin-development/), but most of it seems to beyond my grasp.

Comment: What would that "code" button have to do exactly? The same as it does here on SO - indent a code block, and display it in a monospaced font?

Comment: I'd rather it wrapped a selected piece of text in `<code>` tags :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this ckeditor plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/ckeditor-syntaxhighlight/

It's also compatible with the jquery plugin SyntaxHighlighter
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

Try https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codeTag

```
config.extraPlugins = 'codeTag';
```

No additional dependencies.

Comment: This 6 year old question was about CKE 3.4.1, not 4.x.

Answer (score -3):

Get wysiwyg
Browse configuration>wysiwyg

...
Enable the 'source' button.

Comment: I'm not using the WYSIWYG module. CKEditor, as a module, is a separate thing, it does not rely on WYSIWYG. The "source" button displays the HTML source code for the entire text area, which is not what I'm asking about.